# Speaking of data: Large, big or extensive?

Tags: word-choice

I am dealing with a data set containing vast amounts of records.
Am I dealing with big, large, or extensive data?
I want to avoid the term "data set" in this context.

Comment: You deal with **a lot of** data. Or **a large amount** thereof. Why does it have to be an adjective? It does not have to be an adjective. An adjective does not make sense. Do you have large, big, or extensive milk? Voluminous milk, maybe? Or perhaps it's **a lot of** milk, after all?

Comment: It's what we would have called a *big glop of data* back in the day.  (Call it anything you like.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is for general usage, I'd suggest `voluminous data`

Big Data of course has a specific meaning now a days .

Answer (score 0):

Use extensive. Out of the three, it makes the most sense. Big data means a different thing altogether and large data doesn't make much sense regarding your purpose.

Comment: Agree avoid **Big Data** unless you mean the current  IT buzzword. See http://bigdatauniversity.com/courses/hadoop-course/ for example usage.